# How to check for loop value in if else using jinja2

Tags: html, django, jinja2

hy guys i am new in django and i creat a template like this in this template i am use jinja2 if else and according to data it is true but in this code it is not true please check this code and tell me ans

hear `users = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`
and `user.referredby = 3`

```
{% for i in users %}
        {% if "{{user.referredby}}" == "{{i}}" %}
        <h5>referred by : </h5><p>yes</p>
        {% endif %}
```

according this data my if condition is true but in my code this condition is not true please tell me how i check this correctly

Comment: `{% if i == user.referredby %}` should work, although `i.username` won't as `i` is just going to be an integer on every loop

Comment: sir if `users=['1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8']` then it give me result 4 times `yes yes yes yes` how can i break loop if my if condition is true 1st time

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It sounds like you should do this in your view, not in your template

Comment: yes you can make a set in your views to done it easily rather than doing it in templated